# Excel VBA Copy/Paste overwriting same row

Tags: excel, vba

So, after roughly 3 hours or more of searching google and for an answer, I can't seem to find an answer that fits my specific case. I've been grappling with a macro, and finally have it mostly working BUT getting it to copy/paste to a new sheet is vexing me to no ends. Here's the copy/paste lines (also the prior copy/paste that I tried to make work before I gave up on it) :

```
Sub Filtration()

Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("R1")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim writeRow As Integer
Dim percentage As Double

'to create skip conditions for row 1 & 2
counter = 1
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")            
    'second part of skip condition
    If counter > 2 Then    
        'creates condition to ignore blank cells or cells with a zero or negative number
        If Cell.Value = "" Or Cell.Value <= 0 Then

        Else
            'creates a way to ignore offset cells if =< 0 (might need to add in for blank too)
            If Cell.Offset(, -2).Value <= 0 Then
                percentage = 0
            Else
                percentage = Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value                            
            End If    
            'divide the current cell's value by the the cell one column over's value and compare
            If percentage > 0.02 Then                
                Set Mastersheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' Copy From this sheet
                Set Pastesheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")  ' to this sheet
                Cell.EntireRow.Copy  ' copy the row from column O that meets that requirements (above, 1 and also win in Q)
                'Pastesheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

                Dim LastRow As Long
                With Pastesheet
                    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column "A
                    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With                
            End If
        End If

    End If

    'final part of skip condition to ignore the two headers - has to be here to work, before next but after the last End IF
    counter = counter + 1        
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The commented copy/paste just errors out on me on the `writeRow` part and couldn't figure out why, and searching turned up no reasons either. The second half works but just overwrites the same row over and over, and all the answers and examples I found out there claim it should work, so I'm at a loss. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is `Pastesheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` suppose to be ? is it suppose to be the first empty cell at column A of `Pastesheet` ?

Comment: Do you have a loop somewhere? How do you increment the value of lastRow so that the data gets pasted in the next available row?

Comment: @ShaiRado It should be for the first empty row, or that's what I was led to believe anyway, still pretty new to this.

@Xabier Yes, there are loops in the over all macro. And as far as I know (I'm pretty green at all this) that was sufficent at `lastRow+1` so if it isn't, what do I need to do. Would I need to add a line to the effect of something like `lastRow = lastRow + 1` underneath that?

Comment: OK, and from which `Cell` in `Mastersheet` do you want to copy the row ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I wish to copy the whole row based off an If Then calculation for R column/cells, that part works, just keep overwriting that same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are after something like the code below (this section of code takes care only for the ***Paste*** section):

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCell As Range

With Pastesheet
    ' safer way to get the last row
    Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LastCell.Row
    End If

    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With
```

Comment: Still having that same issue, it pastes and overwrites that same row over and over.

Comment: @George  you need to add your other section if relevant code, the error could be found there

Comment: Ok, updated to the full macro. Everything else seems to run like a top, the copy/paste is my last hold up.

Comment: @George try edited code, a safer way to get the last row